# Scrapy is performing slower on a better device than on a worse device and I can't understand why

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

The devices that I'm talking about have the following specs:

->desktop PC, Intel i5 4690, 16 gigs of ram, ethernet connection (~500mbps download, ~750mbps upload)

->laptop, Intel i7-3520M, 8 gigs of ram, wi-fi connection (~100mbps download, ~120upload)

The download + upload connection speeds were tested using speedtest.net, making sure that the requests go to the same server, so there will be no mismatch between the two devices.

I'm using literally the same code for both devices. I've written it on the desktop computer, then I just transferred the whole project onto the laptop.

First, let me show you the scrapy bench results:

```
laptop (worse)
2021-09-05 12:56:25 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 113852,
 'downloader/request_count': 293,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 293,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 730855,
 'downloader/response_count': 293,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 293,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 10.813298,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_timeout',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 5, 9, 56, 25, 216524),
 'log_count/INFO': 20,
 'request_depth_max': 13,
 'response_received_count': 293,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 293,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 293,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 5859,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 5859,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 5, 9, 56, 14, 403226)}
```

```
desktop
2021-09-05 13:13:50 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 216900,
 'downloader/request_count': 503,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 503,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1467597,
 'downloader/response_count': 503,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 503,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 10.689637,
 'finish_reason': 'closespider_timeout',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 5, 10, 13, 50, 146422),
 'log_count/INFO': 20,
 'request_depth_max': 19,
 'response_received_count': 503,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 503,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 503,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 10060,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 10060,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 5, 10, 13, 39, 456785)}
2021-09-05 13:13:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (closespider_timeout)
```

Scrapy has way better bench stats on the desktop.

Here's my spider, just to see what I'm using, because as I said the exact same spider is on both devices.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class ExampleSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'example'
    
    def init_request(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https://www.ejobs.ro/',
            wait_time=3,
            callback=self.search
        )

        return self.initialized()

    def search(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='keyword']")
        search_input.send_keys("programator")

        search_input2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='s2id_autogen1']")
        search_input2.send_keys("bucuresti")
        selectieOras = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")
        selectieOras.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='submit']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)

        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchSection"))
            )
        finally:
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=driver.current_url,
                wait_time=3,
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):  
        driver = response.meta['driver'] 
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchSection"))
            )
        finally:
            html = driver.page_source
            response_obj = Selector(text=html)
            
            links = response_obj.xpath("//div[@class='jobitem-body']")
            for link in links:
                URL = link.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'title')]/@href").get()

                if URL:
                    yield SeleniumRequest(
                        url=URL,
                        wait_time=3,
                        callback=self.parse_res
                    )

            # next = response_obj.xpath("//div[@id='searchPagination']/li[@class='next']/a/@href")
            # if next:
            #     hrefLink = next.get()
            #     yield SeleniumRequest(
            #         url=hrefLink,
            #         wait_time=3,
            #         callback=self.parse
            #     )

    def parse_res(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//h1[@class='jobad-title']/text()").get()
        }
```

What I've tried:

-making sure that I have the same version of Scrapy on both devices (2.5.0 is installed on both)

-making sure that I have the same version of Selenium on both devices (3.141.0 is installed on both)

-making sure that I have the same version of Anaconda3 on both devices (2021.05 python 3.8.8 64-bit is installed on both)

-making sure that I have the same version of Firefox on both devices (91.0.2 is installed on both)

-making sure that I have the same version of scrapy-selenium on both devices (0.0.7 is installed on both)

-I use the same geckodriver.exe (because as I said, I just copied and pasted the project from desktop to laptop)

-creating a new, clean workspace on anaconda, having installed just scrapy, selenium and scrapy-selenium

-flushing DNS on the desktop

-deleting all temp data and browsing data on the desktop

None worked. The only differences that I know are:

-desktop has Python 3.7.415.0, while the laptop has 3.7.315.0 (I don't think this is the problem tbh, if it is just tell me and I'll downgrade the Python version on the desktop)

-the OS on the desktop is Windows 10 Education N, the OS on the laptop is Windows 10 Pro (I don't think this is the problem neither)

The problem is that running that spider on my laptop is WAY faster than on the PC. On the PC, each request will take ~7s (occasionally 6) while on the laptop it takes a maximum of 4 seconds (fluctuating, sometimes a request takes 1s, sometimes 2, sometimes 3, while on the PC it takes 7s everytime, rarely taking only 6s) and I can't really understand why.

I've tried everything that I could think of. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop has more (and maybe faster) ram. Also hard disk speed and the apps running on the background will effect the performance.